# How do i remove a layer from the scene, from another layer. (Cocos2d)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I got this scene my overviewScene, in this scene i add self as layer, and a MainMenu layer.

The overview layer show some stats about the player, and the menu layer is displayed at the top. Now when the player clicks on a menu point in the menu, i want to change the overview layer out with another layer.

But the problem is, i can't seem to remove the overviewscene layer from the MainMenu class, is this even possible?

:: Update ::

i believe this i what i have tried, let me print some code. This is from my MainMenuLayer

```
CCMenuItemFont menu_overview = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Overview" target:self.parent selector:@selector(test)];
```

The parent would be my overviewScene as this layer was added my that class right?

From overviewScene

```
-(void)test { 
// CCScene *scene =[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene]; 
// CCLayer *parentz = (CCLayer) self.parent; 
//[[scene removeChild: cleanup:YES]; 
[[OverviewScene node] removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this would be to have a parent scene that has the "overview", the new layer you want to show and the "MainMenu" layers added as a child layers. This way you can simply do:

```
[self removeChild:overviewLayer]; // overviewLayer is a reference to overview layer
[self addChild:otherLayer tag:kYourTag z:yourZValue]; // otherLayer is the new layer you want added, mind the z index
```

As long as you keep the z index of each layer set correctly to maintain hierarchy this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hey code_burgar, i believe this i what i have tried, let me print some code.

This is from my MainMenuLayer 
            CCMenuItemFont *menu_overview   = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Overview" target:self.parent selector:@selector(test)];

The parent would be my overviewScene as this layer was added my that class right?

From overviewScene

    -(void)test
{
   // CCScene *scene =[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene]; 
   // CCLayer *parentz = (CCLayer*)  self.parent;
    //[[scene removeChild: cleanup:YES];
    [[OverviewScene node] removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}

Comment: Sorry i'm new here, can't i format my text better in comments?

Comment: not in comments, you should update your question instead. SO is not a forum with discussions.